# Distributable/Distributed Web App with VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to build a distributable app using **VueJS**. I'll describe the scene, so that it can be understood better.

Immagine the following:

- Four companies have the same products database
- Each of them has it's own politics, prices, custom colors, parameters, all of which are also stored in that database
- These 4 companies want to integrate into their relative websites a page which shows their own catalogue (with their custom prices and politics and whatever), as well as, when you click on some of the products, the related information about that product

The question is: how can I make such an app using **VueJS**? Write it once and distribute it to these 4 different company websites?

And I've started to answer to my question doing the following:

- I created an API which can be accessed by API Keys
- Assigned to each company its very own API Key, so that requests coming with that API Key are associated with the given company
- I created an app using **VueCLI** (which uses **vue-router**, for the pages/views, and **axios** for the API calls as well), wrote all my logic and components and styles and whatever else...and for development purposes I tried to use one of the 4 API keys (hard coding it into the axios.defaults.headers) to see if it all works...and it does!

Now, here comes the problem: **I need to build/export the app in such a way that I can do something like this**:

In www.company1.com/catalogue
Call catalogue.js and pass it the company1 API key

In www.company2.com/catalogue
Call catalogue.js and pass it the company2 API key

In www.company3.com/catalogue
Call catalogue.js and pass it the company3 API key

... I'll omit the company4 cause i'm sure you already got me.

Obviously I could export 4 different versions with the hard coded 4 different API's...but seems like a pretty stupid idea to me! Also, it exposes my client a lot cause, well, everybody could link to some of the companies' catalogue.js and, without configuration or whatever, visualise on it's own website my clients products..(which is obviously a problem).

I would like to have:

**ONLY ONE catalogue.js** file with some **exposed parameters**, as, for example: the API Key needed to identify the company.

In this way, everybody could still use that catalogue.js file, but with wrong credentials, it wouldn't produce a thing (i.e. will get an API error of unrecognized API key).

How on earth am I supposed to do this?
I'm banging my head on the wall from 2 weeks.
I've tried to export the app as **Library**, get errors  like: `Unknown custom element: <router-link> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.`

I tried to export the app as **Web Component**...got same error and others as well.

Please help me understand where I go wrong, and how should I approach the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look into Vue Environment Variables https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Or you can make independent `settings.json` file and load it through the axios

Comment: Ok..but how this would help me? I can also have all my settings stored in the database and load them through axios..but the question is: axios uses the API, which requires a KEY. So..we're back to the first point.

To be clear I need something like the Google Maps thing. Everybody on the planet loads the same single maps.js. And then, when you instantiate it, you configure it with your API Key and all the customisations and whatever..

Comment: You need to specify your question, make it less common and insert the examples of code to let us try to understand your problem and offer a suitable solution
If you need some customisable reusable module you can make your own Vue.js component

Comment: My problem is, i guess, structural. My app works fine..I don't have problems with writing components, routes, and whatever. My question is more conceptual.

If you read my question, and have that situation, what would you do? What are the possibilities with VueJS? Is even VueJS the right tool for doing that?

Even if I provide some code..i don't see how that can be useful. I'm not having a syntax error..i'm asking how to structure the app so that answers to the requirements i've written.

Comment: Basically, I need some way to build the app without the instantiation code..so that I can then instantiate the app in a given container with given parameters. Something like that

Comment: What is a "container" practically in your environment? How would you pass the settings or parameters to your app within that container?